# Dynamically added content is not resizing container correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have stripped down my code to the minimum that does what I want and still shows the problem.

I have a dialog that has three parts: header, content and footer. The dialog content is further broken down into an inner content and an inner footer.

The inner content gets it's data from an ajax call. The data is a collapsible tree. The problem occurs when I click on a node to expand it, the inner footer and dialog footer get pushed off the visible part of the dialog.

The dialog is resizable, and the moment I resize it even by a pixel, the layout immediately corrects itself. I have been working on this for a few days now with no luck. Open to any suggestions.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5p4wm7o1/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Testing Collapsable Trees</title>
        <style>
        ul.tree
        {
            margin-block-start: 0;
        }
        
        ul.tree li:hover
        {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        ul.tree li 
        {
            padding-top : 0.25em;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul.tree ul 
        {
            display: none;
        }

        ul.tree ul.open
        {
            display: block;
        }

        ul.tree li::before 
        {
            height: 1em;
            padding: 0.1em;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: -1.3em;
            top: 0.35em;
        }
        
        ul.tree li:has(+ul)
        {
            text-decoration : underline black double 1px;
        }

        ul.tree li:has(+ul)::before 
        {
            content: '+';
        }

        ul.tree li:has(+ul.open)::before 
        {
            content: '-';
        }
        
        .selectedNode
        {
            color : green;
        }
        
        dialog
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            resize: both;
            padding : 0;
            margin: auto;
            max-height: 25%;
        }
        
        dialog h3
        {
            margin : 0.25em 0;
        }

        dialog button
        {
            margin: 0.33em;
            padding: 0.33em 0.5em;
        }
        
        .dlgbody
        {
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
            grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main' 'footer';
        }
        
        .dlgheader 
        {
            background-color: lightgreen;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            border-bottom: 2px double black;
            grid-area: header;
        }

        .dlgcontent 
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: white;
            grid-area: main;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .dlgfooter 
        {
            background-color: lightblue;
            padding-right: 0.5em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            border-top: 2px double black;
            grid-area: footer;
        }

        .fmbody
        {
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
            grid-template-areas: 'fmmain' 'fmfooter';
        }

        .fmcontent 
        {
            background-color: white;
            grid-area: fmmain;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        .fmfooter 
        {
            background-color: white;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            grid-area: fmfooter;
        }
        </style>
        <script>
        class Tree
        {
            constructor(root)
            {
                this.root = document.createElement("ul");
                this.root.classList.add("tree");
                this.root.tabIndex = "-1";
                
                this.root.addEventListener("click", evt => this.mouseHandler(evt));
            }
            
            toggleCollapse(evt)
            {
                let node = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
                
                if(node == null || node.nodeName != "UL")
                    return;
    
                if(node.classList.contains("open")) 
                {
                    node.classList.remove('open');
       
                    let opensubs = node.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
       
                    for(let i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) 
                        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open'); 
                } 
                else 
                    node.classList.add('open'); 
            }
            
            mouseHandler(evt)
            {
                this.toggleCollapse(evt);
            
                let node = this.getSelected();
                
                if(node != null)
                    node.classList.remove("selectedNode");
                    
                evt.target.classList.add("selectedNode");
                
                this.root.dispatchEvent(new Event("selected"));
            }
            
            getRoot()
            {
                return this.root;
            }
            
            getSelected()
            {
                return this.root.querySelector(":scope .selectedNode");
            }
        }
        
        class Dialog
        {
            constructor()
            {
                this.dialogDiv = document.createElement("dialog");
                this.dlgHeader = document.createElement("div");
                this.dlgContent = document.createElement("div");
                this.dlgFooter = document.createElement("div");
            }
            
            init(opts)
            {
                let body = document.createElement("div");
                body.classList.add("dlgbody");
                
                // Build header
                let title = document.createElement("h3");
                title.innerHTML = opts.title;
                this.dlgHeader.appendChild(title);
                this.dlgHeader.classList.add("dlgheader");
                body.appendChild(this.dlgHeader);
                
                // build div for dialog content
                this.dlgContent.classList.add("dlgcontent");
                body.appendChild(this.dlgContent);
        
                // build footer
                let okbutton = document.createElement("button");
                okbutton.textContent = "OK";
                okbutton.onclick = (evt) => { this.dialogDiv.close("OK"); }
                this.dlgFooter.appendChild(okbutton);
        
                this.dlgFooter.classList.add("dlgfooter");
                body.appendChild(this.dlgFooter);
                
                this.dialogDiv.appendChild(body);
                document.body.appendChild(this.dialogDiv);
            }
            
            show()
            {
                this.dialogDiv.returnValue = "";
                this.dialogDiv.showModal();
            }
            
            getContentDiv()
            {
                return this.dlgContent;
            }
            
            getDialogRoot()
            {
                return this.dialogDiv;
            }
        }   
        
        class FileManager
        {
            constructor(opts)
            {
                this.uiList = document.createElement("div");
                this.files = new Tree();
                this.dialog = new Dialog();
        
                this.dialog.init({title : opts.title});
        
                this.uiList.classList.add("fmcontent");
                this.uiList.appendChild(this.files.getRoot());
                
                let uiFooter = document.createElement("div");
                uiFooter.classList.add("fmfooter");
        
                let label = document.createElement("h3");
                label.textContent = "Content Footer";   
                uiFooter.appendChild(label);
        
                let ui = document.createElement("div");
                ui.classList.add("fmbody");
                ui.appendChild(this.uiList);
                ui.appendChild(uiFooter);
        
                this.dialog.getContentDiv().appendChild(ui);
            }
            
            loadData()
            {
                let tree = this.files.getRoot();
                let data = JSON.parse(testData);
                
                this.build(tree, data);
            }
            
            showDialog()
            {
                this.dialog.show();
                this.files.getRoot().focus();
                
                if(this.files.getRoot().children.length == 0)
                    this.loadData();
            }
            
            build(tree, data)
            {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        if(data[i] == "")
                            continue;
                    
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.textContent = data[i];
                        tree.appendChild(li);
                        
                        let ul = document.createElement("ul");
                        tree.appendChild(ul);
                        tree = ul;
                    }
                    
                    if(Array.isArray(data[i]))
                        this.build(tree, data[i]);
                    else if(i > 0)
                    {
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.textContent = data[i];
                        tree.appendChild(li);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var testData = '["", ["files", "subfile1", "subfile2", "subfile3", "subfile4", "subfile5", "subfile6"], ["images", "image 1"]]';
        var fm = null;

        function init()
        {
            fm = new FileManager({title : "Dialog Header"});
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <button onclick="javascript:fm.showDialog();">Dialog</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Initial]

[image: Broken]

[image: After manual resizing]

Comment: Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xue96pmz/

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion.  My sample data was limited, when I tried this with real data - which was much larger -  it still pushes content of the bottom.  The bottom was the bottom of the page this time so not workable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the `max-height` set for `dialog`. Changed it to `height` and the issue was gone.

(Just run snippet in **full page** to see the result)

```js
class Tree
        {
            constructor(root)
            {
                this.root = document.createElement("ul");
                this.root.classList.add("tree");
                this.root.tabIndex = "-1";
                
                this.root.addEventListener("click", evt => this.mouseHandler(evt));
            }
            
            toggleCollapse(evt)
            {
                let node = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
                
                if(node == null || node.nodeName != "UL")
                    return;
    
                if(node.classList.contains("open")) 
                {
                    node.classList.remove('open');
       
                    let opensubs = node.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
       
                    for(let i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++) 
                        opensubs[i].classList.remove('open'); 
                } 
                else 
                    node.classList.add('open'); 
            }
            
            mouseHandler(evt)
            {
                this.toggleCollapse(evt);
            
                let node = this.getSelected();
                
                if(node != null)
                    node.classList.remove("selectedNode");
                    
                evt.target.classList.add("selectedNode");
                
                this.root.dispatchEvent(new Event("selected"));
            }
            
            getRoot()
            {
                return this.root;
            }
            
            getSelected()
            {
                return this.root.querySelector(":scope .selectedNode");
            }
        }
        
        class Dialog
        {
            constructor()
            {
                this.dialogDiv = document.createElement("dialog");
                this.dlgHeader = document.createElement("div");
                this.dlgContent = document.createElement("div");
                this.dlgFooter = document.createElement("div");
            }
            
            init(opts)
            {
                let body = document.createElement("div");
                body.classList.add("dlgbody");
                
                // Build header
                let title = document.createElement("h3");
                title.innerHTML = opts.title;
                this.dlgHeader.appendChild(title);
                this.dlgHeader.classList.add("dlgheader");
                body.appendChild(this.dlgHeader);
                
                // build div for dialog content
                this.dlgContent.classList.add("dlgcontent");
                body.appendChild(this.dlgContent);
        
                // build footer
                let okbutton = document.createElement("button");
                okbutton.textContent = "OK";
                okbutton.onclick = (evt) => { this.dialogDiv.close("OK"); }
                this.dlgFooter.appendChild(okbutton);
        
                this.dlgFooter.classList.add("dlgfooter");
                body.appendChild(this.dlgFooter);
                
                this.dialogDiv.appendChild(body);
                document.body.appendChild(this.dialogDiv);
            }
            
            show()
            {
                this.dialogDiv.returnValue = "";
                this.dialogDiv.showModal();
            }
            
            getContentDiv()
            {
                return this.dlgContent;
            }
            
            getDialogRoot()
            {
                return this.dialogDiv;
            }
        }   
        
        class FileManager
        {
            constructor(opts)
            {
                this.uiList = document.createElement("div");
                this.files = new Tree();
                this.dialog = new Dialog();
        
                this.dialog.init({title : opts.title});
        
                this.uiList.classList.add("fmcontent");
                this.uiList.appendChild(this.files.getRoot());
                
                let uiFooter = document.createElement("div");
                uiFooter.classList.add("fmfooter");
        
                let label = document.createElement("h3");
                label.textContent = "Content Footer";   
                uiFooter.appendChild(label);
        
                let ui = document.createElement("div");
                ui.classList.add("fmbody");
                ui.appendChild(this.uiList);
                ui.appendChild(uiFooter);
        
                this.dialog.getContentDiv().appendChild(ui);
            }
            
            loadData()
            {
                let tree = this.files.getRoot();
                let data = JSON.parse(testData);
                
                this.build(tree, data);
            }
            
            showDialog()
            {
                this.dialog.show();
                this.files.getRoot().focus();
                
                if(this.files.getRoot().children.length == 0)
                    this.loadData();
            }
            
            build(tree, data)
            {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    if(i == 0)
                    {
                        if(data[i] == "")
                            continue;
                    
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.textContent = data[i];
                        tree.appendChild(li);
                        
                        let ul = document.createElement("ul");
                        tree.appendChild(ul);
                        tree = ul;
                    }
                    
                    if(Array.isArray(data[i]))
                        this.build(tree, data[i]);
                    else if(i > 0)
                    {
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        li.textContent = data[i];
                        tree.appendChild(li);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var testData = '["", ["files", "subfile1", "subfile2", "subfile3", "subfile4", "subfile5", "subfile6"], ["images", "image 1"]]';
        var fm = null;

        function init()
        {
            fm = new FileManager({title : "Dialog Header"});
        }
```

```css
ul.tree
        {
            margin-block-start: 0;
        }
        
        ul.tree li:hover
        {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        ul.tree li 
        {
            padding-top : 0.25em;
            list-style-type: none;
            position: relative;
        }

        ul.tree ul 
        {
            display: none;
        }

        ul.tree ul.open
        {
            display: block;
        }

        ul.tree li::before 
        {
            height: 1em;
            padding: 0.1em;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            left: -1.3em;
            top: 0.35em;
        }
        
        ul.tree li:has(+ul)
        {
            text-decoration : underline black double 1px;
        }

        ul.tree li:has(+ul)::before 
        {
            content: '+';
        }

        ul.tree li:has(+ul.open)::before 
        {
            content: '-';
        }
        
        .selectedNode
        {
            color : green;
        }
        
        dialog
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            resize: both;
            padding : 0;
            margin: auto;
            height: 25%;  
        }
        
        dialog h3
        {
            margin : 0.25em 0;
        }

        dialog button
        {
            margin: 0.33em;
            padding: 0.33em 0.5em;
        }
        
        .dlgbody
        {
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
            grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main' 'footer';
        }
        
        .dlgheader 
        {
            background-color: lightgreen;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            border-bottom: 2px double black;
            grid-area: header;
        }

        .dlgcontent 
        {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: white;
            grid-area: main;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .dlgfooter 
        {
            background-color: lightblue;
            padding-right: 0.5em;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            border-top: 2px double black;
            grid-area: footer;
        }

        .fmbody
        {
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
            grid-template-areas: 'fmmain' 'fmfooter';
        }

        .fmcontent 
        {
            background-color: white;
            grid-area: fmmain;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
        }

        .fmfooter 
        {
            background-color: white;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
            grid-area: fmfooter;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Testing Collapsable Trees</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <button onclick="javascript:fm.showDialog();">Dialog</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does pretty much exactly what I wanted - as in 98%.  The one thing I didn't like is that if the initial list is small there is a lot of whitespace...  But honestly what you have provided is completely acceptable!  Thanks a bunch!